# Append array to each element of other array in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have this array:

```
a = np.array(([11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33],[41,42,43]))
b = np.array([88,99])
```

I want to get:

```
c = np.array(([11,12,13,88,99],[21,22,23,88,99],[31,32,33,88,99],[41,42,43,88,99]))
```

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have numpy arrays, you could do:

```
import numpy as np
np.concatenate([a, np.tile(b, (len(a), 1))], 1)
```

Or, using `numpy.broadcast_to`:

```
np.concatenate([a, np.broadcast_to(b, (len(a), len(b)))], 1)
```

output:

```
array([[11, 12, 13, 88, 99],
       [21, 22, 23, 88, 99],
       [31, 32, 33, 88, 99],
       [41, 42, 43, 88, 99]])
```

##### solution with lists:

```
a_list = a.tolist()
b_list = b.tolist()

from itertools import product, chain
[list(chain(*i)) for i in product(a_list, [b_list])]
```

output:

```
[[11, 12, 13, 88, 99],
 [21, 22, 23, 88, 99],
 [31, 32, 33, 88, 99],
 [41, 42, 43, 88, 99]]
```

Comment: `np.tile(b, len(a)).reshape(len(a), -1)` -> `np.tile(b, (len(a), 1))`

Comment: Yes, of course, silly me ;) Thanks!

Comment: also one can use `c = [arr_a+b for arr_a in a]`, if a and b are lists (or converted to lists) :)

Comment: @HadarSharvit yes of course, but I love itertools :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use NumPy [append](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(([11,12,13],[21,22,23],[31,32,33],[41,42,43]))
b = np.array([88,99])

c= np.array([np.append(arr, b) for arr in a  ])
```

Output:

```
array([[11, 12, 13, 88, 99],
       [21, 22, 23, 88, 99],
       [31, 32, 33, 88, 99],
       [41, 42, 43, 88, 99]])
```